# Pine Script not running through all points , holds one entry and no exit

Tags: pine-script

Find below code for 10 SMA to 20 SMA crossover which is not working somehow

```
//@version=5
    strategy(' MA Crossover ', overlay=true)
    start = timestamp(2007, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    end = timestamp(2022, 03, 21, 0, 0)
    ema1 = ta.sma(close, 10)
    ema2 = ta.sma(close, 20)
    plot(ema1, title='EMA 11', color=color.new(color.green, 0))
    plot(ema2, title='EMA 20', color=color.new(color.blue, 0))
    LongEntry = ta.crossover(ema1, ema2)
    LongExit = ta.crossover(ema2, ema1)
    
    strategy.entry('Long Entry', strategy.long, when=LongEntry)
    strategy.close('Long Exit', when=LongExit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter of `strategy.close()` is `id`.

> id (series string) A required parameter. The order identifier. It is
> possible to close an order by referencing its identifier.

You need to pass the id of the trade you want to close. In your case it should be:

```
strategy.close('Long Entry', when=LongExit)
```